# Quartz retain state of existing trigger on redeploy

Tags: java, spring, triggers, quartz-scheduler

I have a Quartz trigger created through Spring Framework which I occasionally need to pause (TRIGGER_STATE=PAUSED). However, if I do a deploy of the application while the trigger is paused it gets un-paused due to the trigger being recreated.  Is there a Quartz setting to retain the trigger state if the trigger already exists?

```
<bean id="updateJobQuartzTrigger"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="name" value="updateTrigger" />
    <property name="group" value="updateDaily" />
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="updateJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 4 * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean name="updateJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="name" value="updateJob" />
    <property name="group" value="updateDaily" />
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.project.quartz.SendMessageJob" />
    <property name="jobDataMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="messageContent">
                <map>
                    <entry key="job" value="UpdateLoad"/>
                </map>
            </entry>
        </map>            
    </property>
    <property name="durability" value="true"/>
</bean>
```